# Why is pyspark throwing "'Column' object is not callable" when trying Window function?

Tags: pyspark

Release label:emr-5.24.0
Hadoop distribution:Amazon 2.8.5
Applications:Spark 2.4.2, Hive 2.3.4

I am trying to get a count of distinct models for each year and have that count appear as a separate column for each record.

Starting with:

```
prod_schema = StructType([
       StructField("model", StringType(), False),          
       StructField("year", StringType(), False),          
       StructField("price", IntegerType(), False),          
       StructField("mileage", IntegerType(), False)]   
       )

dumba = [("Galaxy", "2017", 21841, 17529), 
     ("Galaxy", "2017", 29395, 11892), 
     ("Novato", "2018", 35644, 22876), 
     ("Novato", "2017", 28864, 28286), 
     ("Tagur", "2016", 22761, 62551), 
     ("Tagur", "2011", 11952, 104222), 
     ("Tagur", "2017", 30552, 88045), 
     ("Mulion", "2015", 11054, 35644), 
     ("Mulion", "2018", 15275, 43871), 
     ("Mulion", "2016", 10684, 87112)]

 df = spark.createDataFrame(dumba, schema=prod_schema)
 df.show()

+------+----+-----+-------+
| model|year|price|mileage|
+------+----+-----+-------+
|Galaxy|2017|21841|  17529|
|Galaxy|2017|29395|  11892|
|Novato|2018|35644|  22876|
|Novato|2017|28864|  28286|
| Tagur|2016|22761|  62551|
| Tagur|2011|11952| 104222|
| Tagur|2017|30552|  88045|
|Mulion|2015|11054|  35644|
|Mulion|2018|15275|  43871|
|Mulion|2016|10684|  87112|
+------+----+-----+-------+
```

I'd like to get to:

```
+------+----+-----+-------+---------------+
| model|year|price|mileage|models_per_year|
+------+----+-----+-------+---------------+
|Galaxy|2017|21841|  17529|              3|
|Galaxy|2017|29395|  11892|              3|
|Novato|2018|35644|  22876|              2|
|Novato|2017|28864|  28286|              3|
| Tagur|2016|22761|  62551|              2|
| Tagur|2011|11952| 104222|              1|
| Tagur|2017|30552|  88045|              3|
|Mulion|2015|11054|  35644|              1|
|Mulion|2018|15275|  43871|              2|
|Mulion|2016|10684|  87112|              2|
+------+----+-----+-------+---------------+
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/hadoop/mon/dummy_df.py", line 39, in <module>
df.select(F.col("model").distinct().count())).over(w0)
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

When trying to execute the following code:

```
w0 = Window.partitionBy('year')
df = df.withColumn('models_per_year',
           df.select("model").distinct().count())).over(w0)
```

I'm not sure what the error is trying to tell me, or how to fix it so I can do this operation without using a groupBy (too expensive).  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to avoid a groupBy in your case without losing accuracy because [countDistinct](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.countDistinct) doesn't support window functions currently. When you can live with some inaccuracy, you should have a look at the [approx_count_distinct](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.approx_count_distinct) function:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

prod_schema = StructType([
       StructField("model", StringType(), False),          
       StructField("year", StringType(), False),          
       StructField("price", IntegerType(), False),          
       StructField("mileage", IntegerType(), False)]   
       )

dumba = [("Galaxy", "2017", 21841, 17529), 
     ("Galaxy", "2017", 29395, 11892), 
     ("Novato", "2018", 35644, 22876), 
     ("Novato", "2017", 28864, 28286), 
     ("Tagur", "2016", 22761, 62551), 
     ("Tagur", "2011", 11952, 104222), 
     ("Tagur", "2017", 30552, 88045), 
     ("Mulion", "2015", 11054, 35644), 
     ("Mulion", "2018", 15275, 43871), 
     ("Mulion", "2016", 10684, 87112)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(dumba, schema=prod_schema)

w0 = Window.partitionBy('year')
df = df.withColumn('models_per_year', F.approx_count_distinct('model', 0.02).over(w0))
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+------+----+-----+-------+---------------+ 
| model|year|price|mileage|models_per_year| 
+------+----+-----+-------+---------------+ 
| Tagur|2016|22761|  62551|              2| 
|Mulion|2016|10684|  87112|              2| 
|Galaxy|2017|21841|  17529|              3| 
|Galaxy|2017|29395|  11892|              3| 
|Novato|2017|28864|  28286|              3| 
| Tagur|2017|30552|  88045|              3| 
|Novato|2018|35644|  22876|              2| 
|Mulion|2018|15275|  43871|              2| 
| Tagur|2011|11952| 104222|              1| 
|Mulion|2015|11054|  35644|              1| 
+------+----+-----+-------+---------------+
```